# Can't display the styling for my mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

Having problem with styling my mobile responsive with @media. I can display my container and the navigation on the site but not on my @media.

```css
//========================================================
/* HEADER CONTAINER */
//========================================================

.container
  background-color: #FFF
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row-reverse

.container:after
  content: ""
  display: block
  clear: both
  visibility: none

//========================================================
/* SITE NAVIGATION */
//========================================================

.nav
  //background: pink
  float: right
  display: inline-block

.nav ul li
  float: left
  padding: 10px
  list-style-type: none

.nav ul li a
  text-decoration: none
  color: #333

.nav ul li a:hover
  color: gold
  cursor: pointer

//========================================================
/* RESPONSIVE MENU ICONS */
//========================================================

  .menu-icons
    width: 50px
    height: 50px
    background-color: pink
    margin-left: auto
    margin-right: 10px
    cursor: pointer
    align-items: center
    display: block
    position: relative

    span,
    span:before,
    span:after
      content: ""
      display: block
      width: 100%
      height: 2px
      position: relative
      background: #333

    span:before
      top: 15px

    span:after
      bottom: 17px

//========================================================
/* MOBILE NAVIGATIONS */
//========================================================

@media (max-width: 760px)
  .nav
    display: none
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu-icons">
  <span><div class="bar1">
          <div class="bar2">
            <div class="bar3"></span>
              <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

right now my problem, i can't display anything when i hit the max-width 760px. Also, if i were to indent my "RESPONSIVE NEW ICONS" to be on the same level with my .nav, the actual site for pc will not display, and the responsive is displaying not sure why.

Comment: Is your CSS correct?  It's missing delimiting brackets (`{}`) so it could be getting confused around that.

Comment: You have given display:none for nav in media query. That's the reason why its not getting displayed

Comment: well, except of the `.nav`you don't have any content yet, so since the `.nav` is hidden below 760px, you won't see anything. Add some content...

Comment: Also check your html, what is with this span tag? Open before divs, and closed before divs are closed? And if you wanna use SASS, please read more how to use it, this what you wrote is mix of css way of selecting and sass syntax.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for replying. I have the burger menu icons for the content. It doesn't display both the menu icons and the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use media query like this

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
```

use css like this

```
 .container {
          background-color: #FFF;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row-reverse; 
    }
```

use semicolons and **{ }** in css for defining class style

Comment: All my styling using SASS is displaying. My problem is when i hit the media queries, my content doesn't display.